# Google cloud sql data read audit log

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, audit-logging

I need to log all the queries on my sql instances, filter those that seem to fetch too many rows  and archive it for a period of time.

[Doc](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/audit-logging) says

> (2) All SQL queries executed on the database instance

about "Data Access audit logs".

So I've set out to enable access audit logs for my cloud sql server.
I have checked data read in the audit logs api page as said in [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/configure-data-access#config-console-enable), but I cannot seem to find it anywhere in the log explorer. I have aleady checked log names for "projects/PROJECT_NAME/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access" to no use.

What am I missing? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it in MySQL? And you need to log the query to the Database, not to the Cloud SQL REST API, correct?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes,It's MySQL and yes, it's quries executed on the db. I was planning to send all query records to Cloud Logging first and then proccessing them on a regular basis. Should I turn to turning general_log on ?

Answer (score 2):

To view the logs in Cloud Logging you need to [activate the flag `general_log`](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags#tips) in the [MySQL flags](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags) feature page.

Comment: What puzzles me is what the doc says. It says “all sql queries” when it talks about data read audit log. Now im thinking I should just go with the genral_log flag on.

Comment: If it was Cloud SQL server connected to SSMS, how do we have the logs of operations performed in SSMS in Logs Explorer? The general_log flag which we are talking about is not supported in Cloud SQL for SQL Server.